# Title in SwiftUI Menu/Contextual Menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to add title (Debug Menu) to the `Menu` in iOS? I know it's possible in Swift/UIKit but I don't find a way in SwiftUI.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by @narek.sv's answer, I tried giving the sections headers, and it turns out that works perfectly!

```
Menu("Example") {
    Section("Header 1") {
        Button("Item 1") {}
        Button("Item 2") {}
    }
    Section("Header 2") {
        Button("Item 1") {}
        Button("Item 2") {}
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of a menu with headers]

Answer (score 9):

There is no official solution for that, but you can achieve something similar using `Section`s

```
Menu(content: {
   Section {
      Text("Title")
   }
            
   Section {
      Button("Button 1") {
         print("action 1")
      }
                
      Button("Button 2") {
         print("action 2")
      }
   }
}, label: {
   ...
})
```

[image: example]

Comment: The problem with doing this, is depending on the button that opens the menu location, the menu might be reversed to fit on screen. On iOS 16+ `.environment(\.menuOrder, .fixed)` should prevent this though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple does not provide this function. The title appears as a "button" that calls up the menu, but not again in the menu itself.
Maybe this can be achieved with an own menustyle. You can find information about this here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the confirmation.